# Adding javascript dynamically using ExecuteJavaScriptAsync() API in OnContextCreated event remove elements in HTML HEAD tag ( wpf cefsharp 83.4.20.0)

Tags: cefsharp

I have a web page making ActiveX calls. Currently the page is loaded in IE embedded browser. Now I am planning to start using CEF as embedded web browser. I want to achieve this without modifying the existing code.

My Sample web page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test ActiveXObject</title>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<script type="text/javascript" >

function CallSampleApi()
  {
    var obj = new ActiveXObject("Global.Pref");
    var prefs = obj.Create("Pref.myPref");

    if (prefs != null ) {
        return prefs.SampleAPI();
      }
      else {
        return 'not caught';
      }

}

function myFunction() {

        var message = "<h1 align='center'>Browser is Chrome </h1>" +
                       "<table border='1' width=500>" +
                         "<tr bgcolor='grey'><th width=300>Function Name</th><th width=200>Result</th></tr>" +
               "<tr><td>Call Sample Api</td><td align='center'>" + CallSampleApi() + "</td></tr>" +
                   "</table>" ;

        document.write(message);

}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using WPF cefsharp library for embedded web browser. In my WPF code, i have written a wrapper for this ActiveXObject and adding javascript dynamically using ExecuteJavaScriptAsync() API in OnContextCreated event. This works fine. But the problem is, this code somehow removes all  tag in my html file which is strange.

```
public void OnContextCreated(IWebBrowser browserControl, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame)
{

            if (_script != null && frame.IsMain)
            {
                
                if (frame.Url.Contains("dev")) // avoid dev tools call

                string script = @"class ActiveXObject {
                                           constructor(name) {
                                        }

                                    Create(nativeObj) {
                                        switch (nativeObj) {
                                            case 'Pref.myPref':
                                                return new Preferences();
                                            default:
                                                return null;
                                        }

                                    }
                                }

                                class Preferences { 
                                    constructor() {
                                    }

                                SampleAPI() {
                                    return 'I am caught';
                                }

                            }";

            frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync(script);
    }
}
```

Source of the page loaded in cef embedded browser:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1 align="center">Browser is Chrome </h1>
<table border="1" width="500"><tbody><tr bgcolor="grey"><th width="300">Function Name</th><th width="200">Result</th></tr><tr><td>Call Sample Api</td><td align="center">I am caught</td></tr></tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Not sure how HEAD elements are removed. If i remove onload event from html page and move the content within SCRIPT tag, it works fine.

Comment: Not sure exactly the reason, something to do with document.write replacing the entire DOM. I'd try appending your html to the DOM instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the issue is with document.write called in OnLoad event.